# Dataloader.io not mapping Full Name in import

Tags: dataloader.io

I'm trying to use dataloader.io to import new data to Days Off in Salesforce.  I performed an export on a few Days Off records to see what fields and values are available.  "Full Name" is one of the fields.  When I try to upload a test csv, the mapping does not recognize the Full Name header automatically like other fields, and there is no Full Name option in the Select... menu:
[image: Day Off Insert Mapping]

How do I determine what Header value to use to import a name?

Comment: What’s the API name of the object? Because I do not know an „day off“ object

Comment: Try using 'Name' also share object and field details

Answer (score 0):

Full Name in standard objects like Lead, Person Account and Contact is a formula field derived from fields First Name Middle name and Last Name. In case you desire to update Full Name, please make you include the fields from which it has been derived while retrieving data.
Once you do this, the Full name will automatically be updated.